# Display Error when adding Locations in Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Using Firefox 8.0 on Windows 7

When I go to http://careers.stackoverflow.com and (when editing my profile) try to add a location that can't be found, the displayed error message overlaps with existing elements:

[image]

This also causes the entire list of locations to shift abruptly to the left when displaying the message.

(Additionally, I notice that if I enter "The Moon" then it automatically gets translated to something else:

[image]

Is there something *awesome* in Alabama that I don't know about?)

(And what's wrong with "Space"?  A guy can dream, can't he?)